# Why is the strong law of large number stronger than weak law?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

The weak law is easy to prove, but the strong law (which of course implies the weak law, by Egoroff’s theorem) is more subtle.

I'd like to know for  which  mathematical reason is the strong law stronger than weak law?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: It's stronger because it implies the weaker and is harder to prove, I guess.

Comment: ok, I seek for any proof or any theory show this mathematical reason

Answer (score 4):

The [strong law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) establishes [almost sure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence) convergence.

The [weak law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) establishes convergence [in probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability).

Almost sure convergence [implies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_3) convergence in probabilty. That's why the first variant of the law is *stronger* than the second.